# Set of sequences of real numbers is Vector space of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

"Prove that the set of all sequences of real numbers with the usual operations of addition and multiplication by coefficients by R is a vector space of infinite dimension".

I am thinking of taking the sequences (1,0,0,.....,0,0,0....), (0,1,0,0,...,0,0,...), (0,0,1,0,0...,0,0...) etc but that is the point of I do not know how to reach the conclusion that the space has infinite dimension.

Could you guide me please?

Comment: Show that for any $n\in\mathbb N$ you can find an $n$-dimensional subspace. No finite dimensional space has this property.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is absolutely clear! You helped me a lot, have a nice day!!